# TinyMCE editor keeps old content

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I got a certain module which uses TinyMCE. Basically, I click on an item in a table and it opens a dialog (same page w/jQuery). That dialog contains a tinymce editor which initializes when the dialog is opened. The TinyMCE creates a draft every 30 seconds after changing the content.

Now the only problem is, sometimes when a draft is created and I close the dialog, when I reopen the dialog, the content which I typed (but not saved) is still there.

```
if (tinyMCE.get('content'))
{
    tinyMCE.get('content').setContent(content);
}
else
{
    $('#content').val(content);
}
```

Where `#content` is my textarea. Even if `content` is empty and the editor exist, my old content is sometimes still there.

What exactly could be the problem? If I close the dialog, I also remove all editors like this:

```
var length = tinyMCE.editors.length, i = 0;
for (; i < length; i++)
{
    if (tinyMCE.editors[i])
    {
        closeTinyMCEeditor(tinyMCE.editors[i].id);
    }
}
```

But no luck unfortunately. I thought it was something with UndoManager but that plugin isn't used with my TinyMCE.

Comment: maybe the browser refills the fields (and your editor content). you could try to add a random parameter to your url to avoid this

Comment: What do you mean? It doesn't change the content but it should.